# How to access file path with spaces from command prompt in Java

Tags: java, command-line, apache-commons-exec

I am trying to run a batch file from a Java program. 
For instance: I have a batch "abc.bat" in a folder in "Program Files".

I want to execute this batch from my Java Program. I am using CommandLine class, Commons-exec jar.

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("cmd");
cmdLine.addArgument("/c start \"\" \"C:\\Program Files\\abc.bat\"");

DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine.toString());
exec.execute(cmdLine);
```

The above code throws an error saying "Windows cant find the file. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again". And, that is because of the spaces in the path.

So, I tried the answer provided here by @brso05 and that works. But I want it to be in a Future Class. Please find my code below and help me fix it.

```
final CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("cmd.exe");
cmdLine.addArgument("/c");
cmdLine.addArgument("start");
cmdLine.addArgument("\""+ batchFileExecute.getParent().toString() + "\"");

ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<?> future = es.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
                        try {
                            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine.toString());
                            exec.execute(cmdLine);
                            System.out.println(p.waitFor());
                            }
                        catch (IOException e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        });
                            String thread_status = null;
                            try 
                            {
                                thread_status = future.get().toString(); 
                                System.out.println(thread_status+" completed the execution");
                            } 
                            catch (NullPointerException e) 
                            {
                            System.out.println("The execution of the received project is     complete.");                   
// In here I want to do some processing again.
}
```

The code I mentioned works but it doesnt work if my batch file has a spaces in the path. Can you help me fix this?

Becuase the snippet you've given works but then I cant put it into Future. It doesnt work in the desired manner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work are you sure the file is there?

Comment: yes.. I have tried .. and its not working.. I am trying to run the batch through command prompt from Java..

Comment: Try my answer I think it will work for you...

Comment: I just posted another way to launch less code check out my answer...

Comment: Hey man I just edited my answer it should work now.

Comment: Windows accepts forward slashes.  Then you don't need the double backslashes.  This is a joke http://secretgeek.net/ex_ms an interview with the person who invented "Program Files" :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way:

```
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start \"\" \"C:\\Program Files\\abc.bat\"");
```

Comment: this just gives me a path on my console "D:\Execution\Java>", which I think is the default path of my cmd prompt.

Comment: that works fine for me.. but I have a problem .. I am running this in a loop and every batch has a specific action.. after it completes the action I want the next batch to be executed... For this, I need to use CommandLine class.. but this solution doesnt work for CommandLine...Can you help?  Updated my snipped in my question..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with single quotes? According to [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/commandline.html), it should work.

Comment: See this part, in the provided link:
"Due to the space in the file name we have to quote the file name either with single or double quotes "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same filenames with spaces issue while using ImageMagick. Here is the code to solve the issue:

```
String imageOutput = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream identifyStdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream identifyStderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try
{
    DefaultExecutor identifyExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
    // End the process if it exceeds 60 seconds
    ExecuteWatchdog identifyWatchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60000);
    identifyExecutor.setWatchdog(identifyWatchdog);


    PumpStreamHandler identifyPsh = new PumpStreamHandler(identifyStdout, identifyStderr);
    identifyExecutor.setStreamHandler(identifyPsh);
    identifyExecutor.setExitValue(0); //0 is success

    CommandLine identifyCommandline = new CommandLine("identify");
    identifyCommandline.addArgument(destFile.getAbsolutePath(), false);

    DefaultExecuteResultHandler identifyResultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();

    identifyExecutor.execute(identifyCommandline, identifyResultHandler);
    identifyResultHandler.waitFor();

    if (identifyResultHandler.getExitValue() != 0)
    {
        String output = identifyStdout.toString();
        _logger.debug("Standard Out = " + output);
        _logger.debug("Standard Err = " + identifyStderr.toString());

        String msg = "ImageMagick overlay encountered an error. ImageMagick returned a value of " + identifyResultHandler.getExitValue();
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        imageOutput = identifyStdout.toString();
        _logger.debug("Standard Out = " + imageOutput);
        identifyStdout.close();
        identifyStderr.close();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    _logger.debug("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
}
finally
{
    identifyStdout.close();
    identifyStderr.close();
}
```

The important part here is:

```
identifyCommandline.addArgument(destFile.getAbsolutePath(), false);
```

This line allows a filepath with spaces to process correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When using the CommandLine class `addArgument` method without defining the boolean `handleQuoting`, it will set `handleQuoting` to true for you, basically adding quotes to the argument. This is the method invoking:

```
    public CommandLine addArgument(String argument) {
        return this.addArgument(argument, true);
    }

    public CommandLine addArgument(String argument, boolean handleQuoting) {
        if (argument == null) {
            return this;
        } else {
            if (handleQuoting) {
                StringUtils.quoteArgument(argument);
            }

            this.arguments.add(new Argument(argument, handleQuoting));
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Changing my method from:

```
        CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("pdfinfo");
        cmd.addArgument("-box");
        cmd.addArgument(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

To:

```
        CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("pdfinfo");
        cmd.addArgument("-box");
        cmd.addArgument(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath(), false); <-- change here
```

Solved the issue for me. No quotes were added and the CommandLine was able to find the file.